# Show SVG is not support in your browser when apply

Tags: html, svg

i still developing a web aplication i need show a SVG test file, in major browsers work well, but in old versions the image not show, i want show a custom messasge like canvas tag

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

I inject the sgv file directly in my html

```
<div>
     <svg></svg>
</div>
```

I tried add text between tags `svg`

```
<div>
     <svg>error</svg>
</div>
```

But not show any.

Comment: What are the major browsers and what are the old browsers you are referring to?

Comment: Look into SVG polyfills or a [fallback](http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/)

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides like major broser IE 9+, Chrome 30+, Firefox 25+, Safari 5, versions 5 or 6 years ago or some mobile browsers not work svg. I do not want to know versions of browsers, I just want to display the message, or even use something like modernizer for added functionality, I do not understand the down vote

Comment: It's because you needed to be more clear in your question from the beginning. The downvote is not offensive, believe me i get downvoted a lot as well so i'm worst than you.It's for you to start asking questions more clearly:)

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides What is the problem? svg works in some browsers and not in others. The error only shows when you haven't support and ready. your comment is out of place.